# SSRS - Average of periods with values

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having a problem trying to calculate the average of period totals for periods that have non-zero totals.  The data that's being returned looks like this (simplified)

[Data Being Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKl32.png)

and I'm displaying it like this:

[Format in SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c0q5.png)

What I need is to calculate the sum of all the values (27,377) divided by the number of months with non-zero totals (5).  So it would be 27,377/5 = 5,475.40.

I've tried CountDistinct combined with iif without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom code you have to create a function that will calculate month count

```
Public Dim months As Integer
Public Function MonthCount (month As String, val As Decimal) As Decimal

If  val <> 0  Then
    months = months + 1
End If

Return month

End Function
```

The function takes as parameters the month sum and the month name.
If the month sum if is not equal to zero it increments the month counter.
Finally it return the month value in order to display it in the matrix

[image]

In the cell of the month name value, you call the custom function.

[image]

For your average, the expression should be like the one below

```
Sum(Fields!val.Value, "dataset") / Code.months
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum with IIF expression something like

```
        =Sum(IIF(Fields!TotalCost.Value > 0,1, 0))
```